# Connect to MQTT Broker with .env variables

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I wrote a python code to connect to a MQTT Broker, which worked completely fine until I tried working with environment variables. The library used is **paho-mqtt**.

At first, the `broker`, `port`, `topic`, `password` and `username` were declared in the code, and the code worked well. Then, I created a `.env` file which stores those variables, and now it cannot connect to the broker anymore.

Here's how the **python code** "loads" the environment variables :

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
...
if private_lorawan == True:
    load_dotenv('mqtt-private.env') # loads file
    broker = os.getenv('BROKER')
    port = int(os.getenv('PORT')) # convert in integer
    topic = os.getenv('TOPIC')
    username = os.getenv('USERNAME')
    password = os.getenv('PASSWORD')
```

Here's the **mqtt-private.env** file :

```
BROKER='xxx.xx.xx.xxx' # IP address
PORT=1883
TOPIC="v3/<topic>/devices/<device-eui>/up"
USERNAME="<username>"
PASSWORD="<password>"
```

And here's the **output** when running the code :

```
Connect_mqtt
my-client-0
Loop started
Failed to connect, return code 5
```

When searching what the return code means :

> 5 : **Connection Refused**. The client is not authorized to connect.

I tried :

- username and password in double quotes
- username and password without double quotes

But none of these options seem to work.

Comment: try using the full path for the `.env` file.

Comment: if the above does not work, please show the error message.

Comment: @D.L : Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it but it prints the same error message as before.I tried to print the variable "username", and it prints my computer's username, and not the one specified in the "mqtt-private.env" file. I renamed the key and now it can connect to the broker, but I have no clue why this happened.

Comment: so you can connect one way (username and password), but not the other way (with dotenv) ?

Comment: suggests that the `.env` file is not well constructed.  I tend to read `json` files to obtain those details...

Comment: @D.L : Yes exactly, it works only when the username and password are declared directly in the code. The other way, it loads a different username from the one specified in the `.env` file. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/):

> By default, load_dotenv doesn't override existing environment variables.

`USERNAME` is set to the login name in many operating systems, so the result you are seeing is to be expected. Solutions include using a different variable name, loading the data into a `dict` (`dotenv_values`), and specifying `override` -   `load_dotenv(dotenv_path='mqtt-private.env', override=True)`.